# WPS Office 2019 cannot run on a server?

Tags: terminal-services, wps-spreadsheet

I have recently started to use WPS Office, and it runs well on my PC.
However, when I try to install this on a small terminal server I cannot start any application.

I know  that the default install path is a user folder, so that won't work, so I installed it to various other folders to try it out, including c:\Program Files.
However, this changes nothing.

I cannot start a WPS spreadsheet or a presentation. 
Curiously, Writer starts.

Do I need to use the Premium or Professional version?

I would like to try the Professional version but the "trial" version they have on the website is identical to the free version, so I won't see any difference. Or is there no difference?

I reached out to WPS support but no answer so far.

Anyone has any data on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what we gathered, install and run WPS Office via Windows Server RDS is possible and only supported with an Enterprise deal, the deliverable includes a specific installer for this kind of deployment scenario.

Comment: Thank you and this is correct - we had to contact WPS Enterprise support (on their website) and get them to give an offer. This is not free of charge though.

Answer (score 0):

Only client versions of Windows are listed as supported,
no Server versions, so getting a paid subscription of WPS Office will not help.

From the [WPS Store](https://www.wps.com/store/) :

[image]